# How to show all the content of list view row

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am working with Xamarin forms in order to make a crossplatform APP.

I am using a list view but I can't figure how to make a row show it's full content
[image]

I tried to add HasUnevenRows="True" but didn't do the trick. I also tried to fix RowHeight="100"

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Did you tried RowHeight="100" when HasUnevenRows is false

Comment: It looks like you've set the `LineBreakMode` to `TailTruncation`

Comment: Changed LineBreakMode  still the same thing and Yes i tried HasUnevenRows is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListView RowHeight="100" x:Name="ContextDemoList">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
         <StackLayout Padding="5">
              <Label VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding title}" />
         </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

Comment: My items source was an ObservableCollection<string> so I had to add your code to my list view and change it to Text="{Binding}". thanks for your help